# Перенос списка с помощью шаблона в таблицу html. Python генерация html страницы

Tags: python, html, list, шаблоны, jinja2

есть список который выгружается в шаблон:

```
    {% for elem in admix %}
<table>
    <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Код замеса</th>
        <th>Продукция</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
      <td>{{elem[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{production}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{elem[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{production2}}</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>{{elem[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{production2}}</td>
    <tr>
        <td>{{elem[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{production2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{elem[4]}}</td>
        <td>{{production2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{elem[5]}}</td>
        <td>{{production2}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Итого</th>
        <td>{{total_prod}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

При генерации страницы элемент записывается не как строка в таблицу, а каждое значение строки в отдельную ячейку.

```
<table>
    <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Код замеса</th>
        <th>Продукция</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Итого</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать чтобы элемент записывался как строка в ячейку?
В индексной странице должно быть так:

```
<tr>        
  <td>0005</td>
</tr>
```

На картинке указан не правильный результат присоединения списка к ячейкам таблицы:
[image: полученный результат при генерации страницы]

Если два списка добавить получается не совсем то, что нужно.

```
<table>
    <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Код замеса</th>
        <th>Продукция</th>
    </tr>
{% for elem in admix %}
{% for prod in prodmix %}
    <tr>        
      <td>{{elem}}</td>
      <td>{{prod}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <th>Итого</th>
        <td>{{total_prod}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Из SQL я получаю значения в виде списка с типом данных list

```
rows2 = cur2.fetchall()
```

Это результат запроса с SQL узнать какие элементы хранятся в столбце и подсчитать количество одинаковых значений.

```
print(rows2)
[('0005', 112), ('0006', 128), ('0012', 90)]
```

Получается элемент 0005 - 112 шт. одинаковых элементов и т.д
Списком извлекаю названия элементов:

```
res = [str(row[0]) for row in rows2]
print(res)
['0005', '0006', '0012']
```

я список res сразу отправляю через jinja2 в шаблон. И тут когда нужно в шаблоне заполнить переменную {prod} появляется проблема. Значения второго списка нужно умножить на 1.5 полученный результат передать в шаблон в виде списка и просуммировать полученный результат, чтобы записать в  переменную {{total_prod}}.

```
res2 = [int(row[1]) for row in rows2]
print(res2)
[112, 128, 90]
```

Еще какая особенность полученный результат должен быть привязан к элементу из первого списка. Т.е результат элемента 0005 такой: 112*1,5=168

**UPD:**

```
    cur2.execute(sql_2)

rows = cur1.fetchall()
rows2 = cur2.fetchall()

res = [str(row) for row in rows2]
total = 0
print(res)

for name, number in rows2:
    value = int(number * 1.5)
    # total += value

    res.append((name, value))
f.write(template.render(q=rows, admix_prodmix=res, total_prod=total))
```

Ошибка:

```
{% for admix_elem, prodmix_elem in admix_prodmix %}
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то должно быть так:

```
<table>
    <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Код замеса</th>
        <th>Продукция</th>
    </tr>
    {% for elem in admix %}
    <tr>        
      <td>{{elem}}</td>
      <td>{{production}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <th>Итого</th>
        <td>{{total_prod}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**UPD.**

Просто нужно подготовить список и результат

```
res = []
total = 0

for name, number in cur2.fetchall():
    value = int(number * 1.5)
    total += value

    res.append((name, value))
```

Тогда в шаблон передаете:

```
    return render_template(..., admix_prodmix=res, total_prod=total)
```

Тогда в шаблоне можно будет сделать перебор сразу по двум спискам:

```
<table>
    <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Код замеса</th>
        <th>Продукция</th>
    </tr>
    {% for admix_elem, prodmix_elem in admix_prodmix %}
    <tr>        
      <td>{{admix_elem}}</td>
      <td>{{prodmix_elem}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <th>Итого</th>
        <td>{{total_prod}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: да, правильно только проблема возникает когда использую два списка

<pre> <table>
  <caption>Таблица производства замеса в тоннах</caption>
     <tr>
   <th>Код замеса</th>
   <th>Продукция</th>
  </tr>
 {% for elem in admix %}
 {% for prod in prodmix %}
     <tr>  
          <td>{{elem}}</td>
    <td>{{prod}}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
  <tr>
   <th>Итого</th>
   <td>{{total_prod}}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<pre\>

Comment: Таблица должна от двух списков разом заполняться? В одной ячейке данные одного списка, в соседней ячейке от другого?

Comment: да, не могу вставить в комментариях как должно быть

Comment: тут как-то можно по другому отправить сообщение?

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос это будет правильнее всего :)

Comment: мне стыдно признаться я не знаю как отредактировать вопрос

Comment: Кнопка `править` под вопросом PS. Чего то знать не стыдно )

Comment: спасибо разобрался, уточнил вопрос. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @wremya, надо было сразу все описывать :) Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо щас попробую

Comment: # total += value за комментировал потому-что выходит ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable          дописал в вопрос

Comment: @wremya, странная ошибка, такого быть не может. Если value это int, то проблем с сложением его не будет. Насчет `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` тоже странное, там как раз по 2 элемента будет из `res` доставаться. Повторю код у себя

Comment: @wremya, а, понял. У вас в начале стоит `res = [str(row) for row in rows2]`, а в `res` должен быть пустой список. Т.е. в цикле в шаблоне мы написали, что ожидаем в списке элементы парами, а у вас там по одному элементу-строке. Насчет `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable дописал в вопрос` мне кажется что у вас тоже какая-то фигня в коде случилась, т.к. у меня код из ответа выполнился успешно и выдал такой результат `print(total, res)`: `495 [('0005', 168), ('0006', 192), ('0012', 135)]`

Comment: В списке RES не 2 элемента, а 6

Comment: @wremya, я написал что там элементы парами идут. Строго говоря, в `res` добавляются кортежи по два элемента каждый, в первом добавляется строка (`name`), во втором число (`value`). В цикле с `for admix_elem, prodmix_elem in admix_prodmix`, каждый элемент (кортеж), будет распакован в переменные `admix_elem` и `prodmix_elem`. Например если первый элемент списка `('0005', 168)`, то в  `admix_elem = '0005'` и `prodmix_elem = 168`. Если элементов слишком много, то будет та ошибка. Кст, строки тоже можно распаковывать по-элементно или на подстроки

Comment: спасибо, да все работает. Так доходчиво объяснили ;)

Comment: @wremya, пожалуйста :)